# Triple DES implementation by DES

Tags: c, des, 3des, tripledes

I'm trying to implement 3Des by using a DES API as below:

```
des(input, output, key, mode)
```

which input, output and key are 8 bytes each one and mode identifies encryption and decryption type.
I'm wondering if it's possible to have a 3Des algorithm with variable output length?

This is the code I've written in C to create 3des with more than 8 bytes key by using this API.

But I have no idea if it's working OK or if it's possible to change output bytes.

```
unsigned char TripleDes(uchar *input, uchar *output,uchar *deskey, int mode)
{
    uchar tt[100];
    uchar tmpInput[100];
    uchar tmpOutput[100];
    int i=0, j=0;

    memset(tt, 0, sizeof(tt));
    memset(tmpInput, 0, sizeof(tmpInput));
    memset(tmpOutput, 0, sizeof(tmpOutput));

    j =  strlen(input);
    memcpy(tmpInput, input, j);
    while(j/8!=0){
        j-=8;
        if (mode) { //Encrypt
            des(tmpInput+i*8, tmpOutput+i*8, deskey,1);
            des(tmpOutput+i*8, tt, deskey+8, 0);
            des(tt,tmpOutput+i*8, deskey, 1);
        }
        else { //Decrypt
            des(tmpInput+i*8, tmpOutput+i*8, deskey, 0);
            des(tmpOutput+i*8, tt, deskey+8, 1);
            des(tt, tmpOutput+i*8, deskey, 0);
        }
        i++;
    }

    strcpy(output, tmpOutput);
    return;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: There are test vectors for Triple DES. Check your implementation against them first.

Comment: *"I'm wondering if it's possible to have a 3Des algorithm with variable output length?"* - It seems you're trying to implement a [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) on top of Triple DES. DES and Triple DES are block cipher which both work *only* on 64 bit blocks. Nothing more nothing less. If you want to handle arbitrary sized inputs, you need to think about the mode of operation and the padding scheme.

Comment: It looks like you implemented the two-key 3DES variant in ECB mode with an unknown padding scheme. This code might read uninitialized memory because you didn't consider padding. Also, please don't use `str*` functions on binary data, because the `\0` might appear anywhere and not just the end.

Comment: Thank you for taking time. Do you have any idea how I can use CBC mode in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I finally could solve this problem not by using this API but with the methods are mentiond in the class in below link:

https://github.com/petricek/eternity-service/blob/master/Common/RSARef/source/desc.c

I needed a triple des class in CBC mode with 16 key length. I changed these classes and thos works fine:

```
 DES3_CBCInit
    {
     .....
      deskey(context->subkeys[0], key, encrypt);
      deskey(context->subkeys[1], &key[8], !encrypt);
    }

 DES3_CBCUpdate
  {
    .....

    DESFunction (work, context->subkeys[0]);
    DESFunction (work, context->subkeys[1]);
    DESFunction (work, context->subkeys[0]);

    ......
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
des(tmpInput+i*8, tmpOutput+i*8, deskey,1); // step1: encrypting 8 bytes of input with first 8 bytes of key
des(tmpOutput+i*8, tt, deskey+8, 0);// step2: decrypting result of step1 with last 8 bytes of key
des(tt,tmpOutput+i*8, deskey, 1);// step3: encrypting result of step2 with first 8 bytes of key
```

Assuming you have used 16 bytes key and if des api is doing what I have mentioned in comments, its doing 3DES properly

The length of output data is same as input data, if input data is multiple of 8 bytes.
If length of input data is not multiple of 8, its padded with trailing zeros to make it multiple of 8, and then encrypted
eg
If length of your input data is 10, length of output data will be 16

Comment: Thank you for taking time. That's right but sometimes I need to generate MAC with 8 bytes length from a for example 40 bytes data and sometimes I want to encrypt 16 bytes of data and have 16 encrypted bytes in CBC mode.

Comment: *"If length of input data is not multiple of 8, its padded with trailing zeros to make it multiple of 8"* - How do you know that? Padding is not part of the code here. It simply takes whatever bytes are in the uninitialized memory and treats that as padding which it is not.

Comment: In second para, I am mentioning the general practice is to pad with trailing zeros, to divide entire data in 8 byte blocks

Comment: The general practice is to use [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7), not null padding. Also null padding can not be used with binary data.